# Searching for words that are contained in other words

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Let's say that one of my fields in the index contains the word entrepreneurial.  When I search for the word entrepreneur I don't get that document.  But entrepreneur* does.

Is there a mode/parameter in which queries search for document that have words that contain a word token in search text?

Another example would be finding a doc that has Matthew when you're looking for Matt.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like its doing an exact match search unless you specify it otherwise using *. Perhaps you could append * to the end of the search query using a script.

Comment: Yeah - I did consider this but I'd have to parse and tokenize the search input which is not rocket science but not a simple task either. I was hoping azure search has thought of this and has a parameter mode that acts this way.

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently have a mode where all input terms are treated as prefixes. You have a few options depending of what exactly are you looking for:

1. Set the target searchable field to a language specific analyzer. This is the nicest option from the linguistics perspective. When you do this, if appropriate for the language we'll do stemming which helps with things such as "run" versus "running". It won't help with your specific sample of "entrepreneurial" but generally speaking this helps significantly with recall.
2. Split search input before sending it to search and add "*" to all. Depending on your target language this is relatively easy (i.e. if there are spaces) or very hard. Note that prefixes don't mix well with stemming unless take them into account and search both (e.g. something like search=aa bb -> (aa | aa*) (bb | bb*))
3. Lean on suggestions. This is more of a different angle that may or may not match your scenario. Search suggestions are good at partial/prefix matching and they'll help users land on the right terms. You can read more about this [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/23/announcing-new-enhancements-to-azure-search-suggestions/).

Comment: Pablo - thank you for the clarification.  Your second point is about inserting * after the individual tokens, correct?  The Quotes don't have anything in them so I wanted to make sure I understood it.  Do you happen to have any c# code to parse an arbitrary expression in to its tokens with an ability to re-constitute it from the modified tokens (ie. having added * to all of them)?  Or is there any github source you can point me to?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this page might be of interest..?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798927.aspx

```
search=[string]
```

Optional. The text to search for. All searchable fields are searched by
default unless searchFields is specified. When searching searchable fields, the search text itself is tokenized, so multiple terms can be separated by white space (e.g.: search=hello world). To match any term, use * (this can be useful for boolean filter queries). **Omitting this parameter has the same effect as setting it to** *. See Simple query syntax in Azure Search for specifics on the search syntax.

Comment: Thank you - but I have seen this.  I am looking for a mode in the search that can interpret something like this: (matt|entrepreneur) as (matt*|entrepreneur*).  The user will just type matt and will expect documents with Matthew to come up or they will type entrepreneur and will expect a doc that contains the word entrepreneurial to come up in the search results.  That's just how users expect search to work.  My concern in insert the * myself is complex expressions will require me to write a parser to tokenize the words and add * at the end of every search token...

Comment: It would appear that the search is tokenised by default, so perhaps just appending * to the end would produce the desired effect quite simply?